# Avoiding nested if statements

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I occasionally find myself bumping into code like this (either in other projects or banging out initial prototypes myself):

```
 if @product.save 
   if current_member.role == "admin" 
     redirect_to krowd_path(@product) 
   else 
     redirect_to new_product_offer_path(@product) 
   end 
 else 
   render :new 
 end
```

What is a good way to avoid this type of situation all together?

Comment: Use small functions that call each other and do not be afraid of multiple return points within one function.

Comment: I am not familiar with rails, but you can avoid one level of nesting by checking the exceptional/rare condition first and returning.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One suggestion is to make the roles two classes, initialize them based on the role and call the save function.

```
 class UserRole
    def save(product)
     redirect_to new_product_offer_path(product) 
    end
 end
 class AdminRole < UserRole
    def save(product)
     redirect_to krowd_path(product) 
    end
 end
 def create_role(r)
    case r
    when :admin
        return AdminRole.new()
    else
        return UserRole.new()
    end
 end


 ....
 role = create_role(current_member.role)

 if @product.save 
   role.save(@product) 
 else 
   render :new 
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

If it matches to your requirements you could implement something like:

```
redirect_to_first_accessible(
  krowd_path(@product), 
  new_product_offer_path(@product))
```

If you use something like CanCan gem, gererally it's defined which action is accessible to certain roles.

Comment: I considered cancan for this case, but there are instances where it's not access based. The arrow code articlesmsup those generic cases, but cancan definitely helps separate when it comes to access.